# FormUrlEncodedContent sending a list of objects / route no deserializing

Tags: c#, json, http

I am attempting to post a request to a route however one of my parameters is being dropped.

I've been attempting multiple ways to send a request like this but I don't seem to be able to quite nail or recognize what is going on. For reference this is url encoded content I am sending:

```
        private FormUrlEncodedContent GeneratePaymentConent(Claim[] claims, bool areChagesSigned, decimal? allowableAmount)
        {
            var content = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"claims", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims)},
                { "isReversal", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(areChagesSigned)},
                { "allowableAmount", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allowableAmount)}
            };
            return new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);
        }
```

The async request looks like:

```
await _httpClient.RequestAsync(GeneratePaymentRoute,
                HttpMethod.Post,
                generatedPaymentContent,
                new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user-agent", ChromeUserAgent) }
                );
```

The route looks like:

```
<HttpPost>
   Public Function GenerateInsurerPaymentForClaims(claims As IEnumerable(Of Claim),
                                                   Optional areClaimsAutoForwarded As Boolean = False,
                                                   Optional adjustmentCodes As String = Nothing,
                                                   Optional skipFirstClaimAdjustments As Boolean = False,
                                                   Optional isReversal As Boolean = False,
                                                   Optional allowableAmount? As Decimal = Nothing) As JsonResult
```

While the parameters for allowableAmount and isReversal are being read/deserialized, the claims is coming up as null.

Am I missing something obvious?

edit: realized I'm not showing but the claims on the request side is:

```
claims = new Claim[] { claim }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in a single `Claim` in `GeneratePaymentContent`, when your route is expecting an `IEnumerable<Claim>`.

This would cause the router to return `null` when deserialising it.

I am assuming that the value of `generatedPaymentContent` in your request is the return value of `GeneratePaymentContent()`.

Comment: Good catch, but I had fixed that already and it didn't fix the null problem.